# How do i fit a square around a point?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Assuming i have the image below,

```
I = [1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3
     1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3
     1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3
     1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3
     1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3
     1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3
     1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2];
```

How can i fit a square of size `two pixels` around the point `(4,6)`?

I have been able to find the vertices using the formula:

```
center = [4,6];
Lowerleftvertex  = center - [-2, 2];
Upperrightvertex = center - [2, -2];
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to go about this. Please I'd appreciate any help or suggestions or advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add 4 edges from vertex to vertex (by replacing values of `I`).

In the following example, I set edges values of `I` to zeros:

```
I = [1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3
     1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3
     1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3
     1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3
     1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3
     1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3
     1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2];

center = [4, 6];

I(center(1)-2:center(1)-2, center(2)-2:center(2)+2) = 0; %Top edge.
I(center(1)+2:center(1)+2, center(2)-2:center(2)+2) = 0; %Bottom edge.
I(center(1)-2:center(1)+2, center(2)-2:center(2)-2) = 0; %Left edge.
I(center(1)-2:center(1)+2, center(2)+2:center(2)+2) = 0; %Right edge.

imagesc(I); %Display matrix I as image (zeros are blue).
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
[x_length, y_length] = size(I);
center = [4, 6];
width = 2;
x_min = max((center(1) - width), 1);
x_max = min((center(1) + width), x_length);
y_min = max((center(2) - width), 1);
y_max = min((center(2) + width), y_length);
I_new = I(x_min:x_max, y_min:y_max);
```

This way you make sure that you do not go over the borders of `I`.